# Can not build My iOS App use Google Sign In SDK (version 2.4.0)

Tags: ios, build, sdk, cocoapods, google-signin

My iOS App use Google Sign in SDK with **Cocoapad**

I recently updated Google Sign in SDK version 2.3.2 to versions 2.4.0 use Pod Update then My App does not build on Xcode with Build failed Message

> ld: library not found for -lGIDExShared clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)

Is there any way to bypass this and add support to the library if the developer of the library hasn't updated their library yet?
Thanks a lot for your help and time.

**Update**

I found solved the question.
remove "-lGIDExShared" in Xcode Build Setting, Other linker flag.
Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: If 2.3.2 is working, why not just use that?

Comment: I just use "pod update", version 2.3.2 is updated to 2.4 automatically. but I don't find the way How to roll-back 2.3.2

Comment: Set your version to `~> 2.3`

Comment: I fixed to "pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 2.3' in My Podfile, however get message  "[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements: - `Google/SignIn (~> 2.3)` required by `Podfile`" on terminal. Thanks I roll back to previous branch my git repository

Comment: Damn :-/ looks like they deprecated the version.

Answer (score 0):

Install it with

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

in your Podfile. It seems the name has changed. I tested this with Xcode 7.1 and CocoaPods 0.39.0.

Comment: thanks to the answer. I Just had to use ver 2.3.2. Until Google update version 2.4.0 SDK document. because the other error messages("Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext', ld: library not found for -lGGLCore" came out, I think  probably Xcode looking for other linked Google libraries.

Comment: When I installed the pod, a large number of dependencies were installed along with it. I didn’t receive any linker errors in a new project. I just wanted to let you know in case you want to give it a shot.